# Buildkit and php binary is called php56

Tags: civicrm-buildkit

I have buildkit installed on my computer however the php command is called php56.

The civibuildkit command fails because it is looking for a command called php.

Is there an easy way I could change the settings in buildkit so it will use the php56 command?

**Solution**

I put a symlink in /home/jaap/php56/php to the php56 binary and then I created a wrapper script.

```
mkdir /home/jaap/php56
ln -s /usr/bin/php56 /home/jaap/php56/php
```

Then I created a script in /home/jaap/bin/civibuild.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH="/home/jaap/php56:$PATH"
/home/jaap/bin/civicrm-buildkit/bin/civibuild $@
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just took a look and the reference to `php` in the bash scripts seems to be hardcoded.  I'm assuming there's already a `php` app with a different version, or else you could just put a symlink from `php56` to `php` somewhere in your path.  So I think your best bet is to:

- Create that symlink anyway, but don't put it in your default path.  E.g. `ln -s /usr/bin/php56 /my/folder/php`.
- Add a line to `civibuild` (or call from a wrapper script) that puts the symlink at the BEGINNING of your path, so it's found before your regular php.  E.g. `PATH="/my/folder:$PATH"`.

By putting the symlink in the path only when `civibuild` is called it won't cause interference with your other applications that rely on a different PHP version to run.

Answer (score 0):

Buildkit comes with a configuration file `app/civibuild.conf.tmpl` (that essentially functions as a wrapper script) that you should consider using instead of writing your own.

Copying it to app/civibuild.conf and adjusting the path to suit your needs should do the trick.

You'll still need to manage the symlink (as you and Jon mentioned).

Comment: I have fixed it with the Jons suggestion. And the civibuild.conf was not the solution in my case as it does not contains a parameters for the path the php executable.

Comment: Hmm, can you not add a directory to PATH variable that contains the php executable you want it to use?